# Using Media3D in IIS hosted ASP.NET Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, 3d

I have developed an ASP.NET website that uses System.Windows.Media dlls to render a 3D Image as a bitmap.

The process is the client page requests a render.
The server then runs the Rendering code and sets the bitmap on the page.

This all works fine in VisualStudio, but as soon as I publish to IIS the rendered image no longer displays. The Bitmap rendered by Media3D is empty!

I am using RenderTargetBitmap to Render the ViewPort3d to a Bitmap.

I believe this is an IIS trust issue but I have been unable to solve it. Does anyone have a clue on how to work around this?

I am using .Net 4.5 and am running on Windows 7 64 bit, but the server that will be hosting it is Windows 8 Server, if that changes anything.
***UPDATE***

Process Monitor was very usefull.
From what I can tell
HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{AC757296-3522-4E11-9862-C17BE5A1767E}\Instance

HKCR\CLSID{AC757296-3522-4E11-9862-C17BE5A1767E}\Instance  NAME NOT FOUND

HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{2B46E70F-CDA7-473E-89F6-DC9630A2390B}\Instance NAME NOT FOUND

HKCR\CLSID{2B46E70F-CDA7-473E-89F6-DC9630A2390B}\Instance  NAME NOT FOUND

These keys could be causing the problem, but i'm not entirely sure what they are, googling the first one comes up with 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
Which refers to Encoder-Specific Registry Entries. Which leads me to believe I am somehow missing the appropriate encoder/decoder for RenderTargetBitmap and BmpBitmapEncoder to work properly from w3wp.exe/ IIS. Where do I find these? I would of thought they came with .NET Framework. Any clues?

These are not requested when I run the website from Visual Studio...

Thanks,
GP

Comment: Not sure, but it could be that this is normally a namespace used for WPF applications and not something seen in WebForms. What functions exactly are you using as there may be a better analogue for non-WPF applications. There could also be permissions errors if the resources needed to generate the media require more elevated permissions than is normally allowed by an ASP.Net app.

Comment: Hey I am loading a 3d mesh and putting it into a viewport3d and then using a RenderTargetBitmap to render it to a bitmap. Where can I find out about these errors? Cause as far as I can see there is no evidence of error. Just no Bitmap produced, which I am assuming is because IIS is unable to gain access to some resource which is needed.

Comment: It can get really tricky to nail down. You might try the MSDN forums. If you have full access to the server you can try some of the Microsoft SysInternals tools. They generate tons of information (way too much) but I've used them to find very specific permissions errors. Try Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)  to see if you can spot any denied resources.

Comment: Yea it looks liked there are some registries that could be causing the problem, but I am really not sure of the workings of windows and this stuff, I updated the original question with some more details. Process Monitor was quite usefull.

Comment: This looks like a session 0 isolation problem. See for example http://www.scribd.com/doc/58343489/Windows-Session-0-Isolation-Impact-on-GPU-as-Service#scribdrcm I am facing a similar issue. In my case it looks like I am going to have to move the 3D image generation code to a user session (i.e. outside session 0) and communicate with that somehow (async named pipes possibly). Horrible mess. Can't believe Microsoft don't have a better solution. Please report on how you progress.